# Is there a way to write a VBA that will fill in a large number of consecutive formulas?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on creating a scheduling tool that looks up departure and arrival times and creates a visual tool. I have 1440 columns, one for each minute of the day, and I've written a formula to compare the Staging time, departure time and arrival time to the minute of that column, which I've indicated in row 1. The formula looks like this:

=IFERROR(IF(AND(W$1<[Depart],W$1>=[stage]),"STAGE",IF(AND(W$1>=[Depart],W$1<=[Arrival]),"IN SERVICE","")),"")

Then I used conditional formatting to highlight the terms "Stage" and "In service" in different colours.  When the column width is reduced to a few pixels, this provides a great visual scheduling toll.

The problem I hear from end users is that this formula, 720,000 times, takes a fair chunk of ram.  I'm wondering if there is a way to reduce the file size by writing a vba that will remove the formulas when not in use and put them back when needed.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In short, you'll need to show your code attempts to solve this and where it's not working to get the most help on this site. If you also post a screenshot of a sample of your sheet, that would help us help you more as well.

Comment: Questions :
1 : Do you really need to cover 24 hours ?
2 : To the minute ? Would it not be better to take a 5 Minutes block ?

If you can answer one Question with " NO " You can Reduce your Amount of Data

Comment: Thanks @moosli Unfortunately, it does need to be minute by minute and previous manual versions of the same tool were over a 36 hour period to allow for overnight work.

Answer (score 0):

You should copy the cells with the formula & then with that same range use `.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`. This will replace the formulas with the values they produce. You should then put in some logic on the worksheet's code so that when the values for [Depart], [Stage], &/or [Arrival] change, the formulas are reapplied, calculated, & then removed again. This way A) you save the formula in code, where it can't accidentally be deleted; B) the user doesn't have to do anything extra to initiate the update.

I'm going to assume the Depart/Arrival/Stage times start in B2 and are in a single column and that the 1440 columns start in column D. Given that, you'd want something like the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'
'Confirm the target is for the Depart/Arrival/Stage values & we didn't just empty the cell
If Target.Column = "B" AND Target.Value <> "" THEN
    Dim r as long
    r = Target.Row
    'Remove old values to be sure we don't carry over anything from the row's prior value
    Range("D" & r & ":BCM" & r).ClearContents
    Range("D" & r).Formula= "[insert your formula here]"

    'Paste the formulas to the rest of the range
    Range("E" & r & ":BCM" & r).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
    'Calculate so we have correct values
    Range("D" & r & ":BCM" & r).Calculate

    'Replace the formulas with values
    Range("D" & r & ":BCM" & r).Copy
    Range("D" & r & ":BCM" & r).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If 'else do nothing, not in the correct range (prevents infinite loops)

End Sub
```

You'll probably need to do some tweaking to account for what data is where & how the updates are done (for example, if you add/remove multiple times at once, you'll want to apply the formulas to the first cell like I did, but then apply it to the whole affected range, rows & columns, in one step rather than one row @ a time.

Comment: Thanks @JMichael. This was my original intent but it's the coding part that's a little over my head.  This schedule is consistently changing and once I paste over the formulas, I don't know how to update the values. I'm still pretty new to vba and code. I'm experimenting with loop functions now to try to solve my conundrum.  If you can expand on the coding option, I would certainly give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input all,

Sometimes the best solution is the simplest. I used the record macro function and rebuilt my chart. I added a couple of screen update commands and it works great. Code below if you're interested.

Thanks.

```
Sub ActiveGantt()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If Range("H1") = "OFF" Then

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("W4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(IF(AND(R1C<RC21,R1C>=RC20),""STAGE"",IF(AND(R1C>=RC21,R1C<=RC22),""IN SERVICE"","""")),"""")"
    Range("W4").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("W4:W717"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("W4:W717").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("W4:BDF717"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("W4:BDF717").Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select

     Range("W4").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy

    Range("W4").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    Range("h1").Value = "ON"


Else

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("W4").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Range("U3").Select
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select

    Range("h1").Value = "OFF"



Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You should try to get rid of the `Select`s they'll bog your code down. Ideally you should refer to the range specifically.

Comment: Will do. Thanks again for your help!